# Adding scroll overflow with container height driven by container's container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an html dialogue box which contain 3 "lists" side-by-side.

1. The dialogue box's height is dynamic and based on the viewport height (using absolute positioning for this).
2. Most of the dialogue box's content is auto height but the 3 "lists" need to consume all spare height and if the list items are too many for the height available, introduce scrollbars without affecting the list container's height.

I've got this working with a single "list" as demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/ruz705kb/37/ or run the following snippet (but as "Full Page" and click "Add" until list extends longer than the list area)

```js
const x = document.getElementById('item-container');
let r = 1;
function add()
{
    var y = document.createElement('div');
    y.innerText = "Item " + r++;
    x.appendChild(y);
}
function remove()
{
    x.removeChild(x.firstChild);
}
// Add some initial items
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    add();
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 2rem;
}

.fixed-inset {
  /* Green area containing single dynamic sized red area */
  background: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 3rem 0 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scroll {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin-inline: 0.5rem;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.scroll > * {
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 1rem 1rem auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Working version with single list.</h1>
<button type="button" class="close-button">X</button>

<div class="fixed-inset">
  <header>
    Fixed Header<br>Fixed Header
    <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add Item</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="remove()">Remove Item</button> 
  </header>
    <div class="scroll" id="item-container"></div>
  <footer>Fixed Footer<br>Fixed Footer</footer>
</div>

</div>
```

In order to get three lists side-by-side however, I need to introduce another intermediate container (display:flex with 3 of the "lists" as children).  When I do this however, if any of the lists extend beyond the height of the box then the height of the intermediate container expands instead of scrollbars being introduced on the list itself.

The three scrollable areas version that isn't working can be demonstrated here:
https://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/asweqmcy/ or run the following snippet (but as "Full Page" and click "Add" until list extends longer than the list area to see the list height increase which I don't want to happen)

```js
const x = document.getElementById('item-container2');
let r = 1;
function add()
{
    var y = document.createElement('div');
    y.innerText = "Item " + r++;
    x.appendChild(y);
}
function remove()
{
    x.removeChild(x.firstChild);
}
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) add();
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 2rem;
}

.fixed-inset {
  /* Green area containing single dynamic sized red area */
  background: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 3rem 0 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tri {
  position: relative;
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1 0 0;

  /* Split content into three columns */
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: stretch;
}  
.tri > * {
  flex-basis: 1 0 0; height: calc(100%);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


.scroll {
  background-color: tomato;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Why is this not being honoured and .scroll area expanding? */
}
.scroll > * {
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 1rem 1rem auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Non-working version with 3 lists</h1>
<button type="button" class="close-button">X</button>

<div class="fixed-inset">
  <header>
    Fixed Header<br>Fixed Header
    <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add Item</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="remove()">Remove Item</button> 
  </header>
  <div class="tri">
    <div class="scroll" id="item-container1"></div>
    <div class="scroll" id="item-container2"></div>
    <div class="scroll" id="item-container3"></div>
  </div>
  <footer>Fixed Footer<br>Fixed Footer</footer>
</div>

</div>
```

How do I force the "list" not to expand the height of it's container, yet allow the container's height to be driven by the available height in the dialogue box?

Here is an image of our end design:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the very same `.scroll` class that worked on the list, on the parent container. Only difference, I removed background colors and margin. Is this the effect you're after?

```js
const x = document.getElementById('item-container2');
let r = 1;

function add() {
  var y = document.createElement('div');
  y.innerText = "Item " + r++;
  x.appendChild(y);
}

function remove() {
  x.removeChild(x.firstChild);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) add();
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 2rem;
}

.fixed-inset {
  /* Green area containing single dynamic sized red area */
  background: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 3rem 0 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tri {
  position: relative;
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  /* Split content into three columns */
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.tri>* {
  flex-basis: 1 0 0;
  height: calc(100%);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll {
  background-color: tomato;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* Why is this not being honoured and .scroll area expanding? */
}

.scroll>* {
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 1rem 1rem auto auto;
}

.scroll-outer {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll>* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Non-working version with 3 lists</h1>
  <button type="button" class="close-button">X</button>

  <div class="fixed-inset">
    <header>
      Fixed Header<br>Fixed Header
      <button type="button" onclick="add()">Add Item</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="remove()">Remove Item</button>
    </header>
    <div class="tri scroll-outer">
      <div class="scroll" id="item-container1"></div>
      <div class="scroll" id="item-container2"></div>
      <div class="scroll" id="item-container3"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>Fixed Footer<br>Fixed Footer</footer>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow.  Yes, that is the effect I am after.  The overflow-y has introduced a second scrollbar (on the .tri / .scroll-outer) but it isn't engaging so I might be able to play around with using `overflow-y: hidden` or something.  You have certainly moved things forward for me though.  Thanks.